How to add ListView footer text in LiveBindings Designer
Why is there no ItemFooter.Text in my ListView3 in Livebindings Designer? Bindable Members doesn't have it either, so I can't add it to the list. I want add a footer text by using Livebindings Designer, not programmatically.
ListView3.ItemAppearance = DynamicAppearance, ListView3.ItemAppearance.FooterAppearance = ListHeader.

I use Delphi 12.
